# Appcelerator titanium - Splash screen with progress bar

Tags: android, ios, progress-bar, appcelerator

I'm trying to setup a custom splash screen that comes up when my ios & android app, built with titanium, loads up for the first time.

The screen would be similar to the default appcelerator splash png that shows up when the app is launched on the emulator.

The screen would have
1. Custom background
2. App logo
3. Progress bar that animates from 0 to 100%

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to put a progress bar on the "Splash screen".

The only way is to have your first window set it's background to the same as the splash screen image with a progress bar on it. The do your long running start up and close the window when done. Generally, however, it is bets not to have long running start ups ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Android, but on the iPhone you can't add anything to the splash screen (Default.png), you can however add a UIImageView subview to the key window so that when the splash screen goes away, the user can't tell, and then you can add a progress bar to THAT. If you code your program to load most of it's contents afterwards you could have some form of progress bar on the 'splash' screen..

I use the same method to make the splash screen appear to "fade away" when my apps load.

Comment: Seems having 2 splash screens is the only way. Would you know how to run an actual progress bar, one that reaches 100% only when the app is done loading? Thanks

Comment: Personally I would use a UIProgressView, then on app start call a function in a new thread that loaded each View in your app, and update the progress bar after each initiation.

Comment: Sounds interesting... Will try it out